# Quick way to disallow inserts on a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have some log events that are coming in and I want to disable them (for a minute) while I debug things. I am able to do things like `alter table` and have full permissions. What might be a good way to do this?

The only thing I can think of (which would block entries) is to add a new FK field that is NOT NULL to some default value (it seems like any other fields such as a `SET` default to `''` or `0` so they will still be inserted).

What might be a good way to do this?

Comment: An exclusive lock on the table comes to mind.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's a good idea. How would that be done? `LOCK TABLES event` Do you have to specify read or write (and can you do both?)